# SQL Server - OPENQUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am using an Openquey which has been working fine on SQL Server 2005, I have 1 server that is SQL Server 2008 which this does not work on.

If I run the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY([Manchester], 
      '[Manchester].[PilotWebApp].[DBO].rsp_HandheldPerformance ''10/01/2009'', 
      ''10/10/2009''')
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot process the object "[Manchester].[PilotWebApp].[DBO].rsp_HandheldPerformance '10/01/2009', '10/10/2009'". 
The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "Manchester" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.
```

If I just run:

```
[Manchester].[PilotWebApp].[DBO].rsp_HandheldPerformance '10/01/2009', '10/10/2009'
```

it works fine. Has something been changed in 2008?

What it does is gets the data from the openquery and inserts into my temp table:

```
INSERT #TempHandheldPerformance SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([Manchester], '[Manchester].PilotWebApp.DBO.rsp_HandheldPerformance ''10/01/2009'', ''10/10/2009''')
```

Answer (score 8):

Even the question it's from 2009, I had the same problem en 2012!! and it was kinda difficult to find the answer....anyway just used SET NOCOUNT ON before executing the SP

if Manchester is the LinkedServer the example code with SET NOCOUNT ON should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY([Manchester], 
      'SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [PilotWebApp].[DBO].rsp_HandheldPerformance ''10/01/2009'', 
      ''10/10/2009''')
```

And to fill the temporary table I do

```
SELECT *
INTO #temptable
FROM OPENQUERY([Manchester], 
          'SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [PilotWebApp].[DBO].rsp_HandheldPerformance ''10/01/2009'', 
          ''10/10/2009''')
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2247200/181766

Answer (score 1):

Check and make sure that there's no linked server named [Manchester] on the remote box; your syntax could be interpreted as:

Connect from local server to a linked server named Manchester, and then execute a stored proc on another linked server named Manchester.

Stu

Answer (score 1):

Try add `SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON;` in your query

```
SELECT * INTO #temptable FROM OPENQUERY([Manchester], 'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC [Manchester].    [PilotWebApp].[DBO].rsp_HandheldPerformance ''10/01/2009'', ''10/10/2009''')
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the linked server is using the same credentials as you are.  You can find them on the Linked Server Properties, then Security Options.

Comment: already checked that and there fine. as if i try and do any other querys on that linked server it worked fine

Comment: Is the default catalog set properly?  Is "RPC Out" enabled (it's required for stored procedure calls) ?